# How to set database fields to server time using nhibernate

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using fluent nhibernate for the first time to phase out my existing database access layer for accessing a remote MySql server.

The clients are mostly virtualized and can go to sleep/hibernate at any point in time, for any length of time (seconds to days). Even though they are usually time synchronous with the server that cannot be guaranteed, which means I cannot use the client provided `DateTime` for some fields.

How do I get nhibernate to set/update certain fields with the server time (preferably by calling the `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` function)?

Object:

```
public class MyObject{
  public virtual UInt64 Id { get; set; }
  public virtual String Status{ get; set; }
  public virtual String SomeData{ get; set; }

  //Set only once when the Object is inserted
  public virtual DateTime TimeCreated { get; set; }
  //Set every time the object is updated
  public virtual DateTime TimeLastUpdate { get; set; }
  //Set every time the 'Status' column is updated
  public virtual DateTime TimeStatusLastChanged { get; set; }
  //This is a user provides standard datetime field
  public virtual DateTime SomeUserSpecifiedTime { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
Id(x => x.Id)
  .GeneratedBy.Native();
Map(x => x.Status);
Map(x => x.SomeData);
Map(x => x.SomeUserSpecifiedTime);
//? -->
Map(x => x.TimeCreated)
  .Not.Update();
Map(x => x.TimeLastUpdate);
Map(x => x.TimeStatusLastChanged);
//<-- ?
```

I want the three `Time*`-fields to use the `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` function, when they are set/updated, so the server side date/time gets inserted. The `DateTime SomeUserSpecifiedTime` field is a standard mapped field.

Until now my database access class contained the logic to create the queries in that way. I could create database triggers with the `.Generated.Insert/Always` mapping, but I was hoping there is a nhibernate/code-only way of doing that.

One solution I have found, is fetching the time from the server and providing it for the insert/update, but that is out, because the time between fetch and insert/update can be significant.

Comment: Why not set the time to UTC instead of server time?

Comment: All times are internally UTC, on the client too. Unfortunately client times may differ, so the only authoritative time is server time. While I'm using ntp time servers to keep time in sync, it's not always enough.

Comment: Just an idea you could calculate a client v. server time offset when the application inits, and use that to setup your server time logic. May not be the most fool-proof solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to solve the problem using triggers, which is not optimal, but works for now. Unfortunately nhibernate does not have a concept of triggers, so you have to declare them as *auxiliary database objects*, which leads to some problems

- SchemaValidator and SchemaUpdate will not pick up on auxDbObjects and thus will not update/create them. SchemaExport will create them, but will do so twice which leads to even more code duplication.
- Need to create and register an instance for each trigger, which is cumbersome.

It might look something like this

```
public class MyTrigger : IAuxiliaryDatabaseObject{

  public string SqlCreateString(Dialect dialect, IMapping p, string defaultCatalog, string defaultSchema){
    //The drop is important, because the shema export calls and executes this twice.
    return @"
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS myTrigger;

CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON myObjectTable FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
set new.TimeAdded = UTC_TIMESTAMP();
END";
    }

    public string SqlDropString(Dialect dialect, string defaultCatalog, string defaultSchema){
    return @"DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS myTrigger";
    }

  public void AddDialectScope(string dialectName){
    throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

  public bool AppliesToDialect(Dialect dialect){
    return true;
    }

  public void SetParameterValues(IDictionary<string, string> parameters){
    throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```

In the configuration each trigger/aux. database object must be added individually:

```
Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(...)
  .ExposeConfiguration(conf =>
    {
    conf.AddAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(new MyTrigger());
    });
```

The mapping

```
Map(x => x.TimeCreated)
  .Not.Update()
  .CustomType("UtcDateTime")
  .ReadOnly()
  .Generated.Insert()   //.Generated.Always() for columns that track lastModification
  ;
```

Custom user types or interceptors do not work unfortunately so it seems this is the only possible way to achieve this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
Map(x => x.TimeStatusLastChanged)
             .Not.Nullable()
             .Default("UTC_TIMESTAMP()");
```

Comment: the `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` function is not a valid default value for a `DateTime` or `Timestamp` column. Additionally it would only work for inserts, not updates.